# Does AWS Athena support set operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, set-operations

Try to use set operation but seems not to work in Athena. Is it not supported or is there anything wrong with the SQL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT cik FROM xbrl
MINUS
SELECT cik FROM xbrl
WHERE year IN (2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2010)
```

> line 3:1: mismatched input 'SELECT'. Expecting: '(', ',', 'CROSS', 'EXCEPT', 'FULL', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INNER', 'INTERSECT', 'JOIN', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'NATURAL', 'OFFSET', 'ORDER', 'RIGHT', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'UNION', 'WHERE',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Athena doesn't support `MINUS`, but usually we can express a minus query in other ways.  In this case, use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT cik
FROM xbrl
WHERE year < 2010 OR year > 2015;
```

Answer (score 0):

for set operation in Athena you can use { UNION | INTERSECT | EXCEPT }

SELECT DISTINCT cik FROM xbrl
EXCEPT
SELECT cik FROM xbrl
WHERE year IN (2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2010)